# getJSON not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

Can someone help explain why the following code works in Chrome and IE, but not Safari.  I believe the issue is somewhere with the getJSON.  It is returning the JSON and works in other browsers, again just not safari.  Thanks

Link to actual page: [Link to actual page](https://googledrive.com/host/0B_mOEVr803HMNkt2RFVUU1JOYXc/index.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Lenward Cunningham" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Louisiana Post Game Scores" />
    <meta name="description" content="Post Game" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="Lenward Cunningham" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <title>Louisiana Post Game</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/acadianaPGicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/_styles.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='header'><img src="img/acadianaPG200.jpg"></div>
        <div id='content'></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFp0U_pYseCIXVUVfK_wOMoTgno76sk-JXDMGmPResdseOX3Xj/exec";
                /*Populate list from JSON   */
                $.getJSON(url) 
                   .done(function(data) {
                        for (var d in data) {
                        /*Process JSON Parameters*/
                        var game = data[d];
                        console.log(game)
                        if (game.matchup) {
                        var matchUp = game.matchup.split('\n');
                        var matchUp1 = matchUp[0];
                        var matchUp2 = matchUp[1];
                        }
                        var score1 = '';
                        var score2 = '';
                        if (game.score) {
                        var score = game.score.split('\n');
                        score1 = score[0];
                        score2 = score[1];
                        }
                        var gameStatus = game.gameStatus;

                        /*if (game.matchup === null || game.matchup === '')
                        continue;*/
                        $('#content').append(
                            "<div class='game'>"+
                                "<div class='team'><span class='rank'></span>"+matchUp1+"<span class='score'>"+score1+"</span></div>"+
                                "<div class='team'><span class='rank'></span>"+matchUp2+"<span class='score'>"+score2+"</span></div>"+
                                "<div class='status'>"+gameStatus+"</div>"+
                            "</div>"
                        );
                    }   
                })
            });
            </script>
        <script>
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

              ga('create', 'UA-51502655-1', 'googledrive.com');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this json format

```
$.getJSON(
   "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFp0U_pYseCIXVUVfK_wOMoTgno76sk-JXDMGmPResdseOX3Xj/exec",
    function (data) {
      for (var d in data) {
                    /*Process JSON Parameters*/
                    var game = data[d];
                    console.log(game)
                    if (game.matchup) {
                        var matchUp = game.matchup.split('\n');
                        var matchUp1 = matchUp[0];
                        var matchUp2 = matchUp[1];
                    }
                    var score1 = '';
                    var score2 = '';
                    if (game.score) {
                        var score = game.score.split('\n');
                        score1 = score[0];
                        score2 = score[1];
                    }
                    var gameStatus = game.gameStatus;

                    /*if (game.matchup === null || game.matchup === '')
                    continue;*/
                    alert();
                    $('#content').append(
                        "<div class='game'>" +
                            "<div class='team'><span class='rank'></span>" + matchUp1 + "<span class='score'>" + score1 + "</span></div>" +
                            "<div class='team'><span class='rank'></span>" + matchUp2 + "<span class='score'>" + score2 + "</span></div>" +
                            "<div class='status'>" + gameStatus + "</div>" +
                        "</div>"
                    );
                }
    }
);
```